# Can I declare only specific elements of an array as constant? (C/C++/Fortran)

Tags: c++, c, arrays, fortran, constants

**Scenario:**
I pass e.g. a 2D matrix as argument in a function and I would like to be able to read and change all the elements, **BUT** *I would like to prevent any accidental writting in let's say the last column*. So I would like somehow to tell the compiler to use specific elements in this function as constant.

Probably it can't be done but it would be useful in some scenarios.

Comment: Compile time impossible. Runtime possible. Would that suffice

Comment: What exactly do you call a 2D matrix in C and C++? They don't have (real proper) 2D arrays.

Comment: @Ed Heal: runtime possible? How? That's interesting...

Comment: @Vladimir F: Sorry if I didn't use the term correctly. In my calculations I have a 2D matrix. In Fortran I would write A(i,j), in C I would write A[i][j]. Although they may be different from a Computer Architecture point of view, for me as a numerical-programming-oriented developer, they are the same and I could use the one or the other language the same.

Comment: hey are not the same as you will find out in application where contiguous arrays are required (yes, in numerical programs too). Notably, I suggest you to avoid the term matrix. It is ambiguous and does not mean anything distinct in any of the tree languages you reference. You probably meant array.

Comment: @VladimirF : I am intrigued as to the manner in which a 2D array in C is not "real".  Please elaborate.  I understand that an array in C and C++ is not a first-class data type - is that what you are referring to?

Comment: @Clifford They are 1D arrays of pointrrs to 1D arrays. Special care must be taken if these 1D arrays are to be anywhere close to each other in memory.

Comment: @VladimirF : Not true; `int x[4][4]` will create a contiguous block of 16 integers - guaranteed.  The guarantee is perhaps indirect; `sizeof(x)` must be `sizeof(int) * 4 * 4`, and using this size for `memset()` or `memcpy()` must include the entire array. Arrays are *always* contiguous regardless of teh number of dimensions.  It is possible to create an *array of pointers* to *independent arrays* and index them in the same way; so you can have something that looks like a true array from the access syntax, but is not contiguous, and for which `sizeof` will not be the sizeof the data in memory.

Comment: @Clifford I just ignore static arrays and VLAs here because their almost zero usefulness for real numerical codes. Dynamic arrays are the only interesting ones. And I kow it is possible to allocate one block and set the pointers to the rows, thats why I alredy wrote "special care must be taken". I have seen too many attempts to pass non-contiguous arrays of arrays where contiguous were required even here on StackOverfloe, that it wasn't woth to count them.

Comment: @VladimirF :  Fair enough, but in the language definition "array" has that meaning, and that was the tern used in the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An array is a contiguous block of objects of *common* type; so what you are suggesting is not supported.

The appropriate solution is to encapsulate the array and access it through functions that can apply your required semantics.  In fact if you used C++ you could encapsulate in a class with The `[]` operator overloaded so that you can apply the semantics you require while still using array access notation.

Answer (score 0):

No, This is impossible. That is because a `array` must be of a common type, and although `int` looks like its the same as `const int`, It is not of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

In Fortran this is not possible. It does not have any two distinct type as `int` and `const int` in the other languages but still you can't just automatically protect a part of array from being modified. The `intent(in)` argument attribute can also protect only the array as a whole.

Just be sure you program your procedure right and test it thoroughly. You can use debuggers to test if a certain part of memory is modified or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sketch of a possibility in C++

```
class Item {
   protected:
      int <or some other type> value;
   public:
      Item(int x) : value (x) {};
      int Get() const ( return value; };
      void Set(int x) { throw std::runtime_error("Oh Dear!");
};

class Settable : public Item {
   public:
      void Set(int x) { value = x; };
};
```

Then a 2D vector (we are using C++) can be

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::shard_ptr<item>>> list;
```

Then fill you boots with one of the other instances of the above objects. Handle exceptions!

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you skip those elements when the user tries to overwrite them.

Comment: The problem is that I can't always feel safe that I am not accidentally writting (not skipping) these elements. If we were always safe, we wouldn't need constants.

Comment: That easy to solve. Have a master array and any point you can make a comparison.